# What is alexandria:ensure-symbol for?

Tags: common-lisp

It seems to do what `intern` does. Maybe `(intern (read sym))`. But what is it for? I see it being used like:

```
(if (keywordp x)
  (alexandria:ensure-symbol x)
  x)
```

In what case might something be a keyword but not a symbol?

Comment: In Lisp development environments one typically can use the keyboard combination meta-. on a symbol to get to its source code. Some development environments also support `(ed 'some-function-name)` to open up an editor window with the respective source code.

Answer (score 2):

A [keyword](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_kwd.htm) is, of course, always a [symbol](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_symbol.htm).

The function in question is [defined](https://github.com/keithj/alexandria/blob/master/symbols.lisp) as

```
(declaim (inline ensure-symbol))
(defun ensure-symbol (name &optional (package *package*))
  "Returns a symbol with name designated by NAME, accessible in package
designated by PACKAGE. If symbol is not already accessible in PACKAGE, it is
interned there. Returns a secondary value reflecting the status of the symbol
in the package, which matches the secondary return value of INTERN.
Example:
  (ensure-symbol :cons :cl) => cl:cons, :external
"
  (intern (string name) package))
```

I.e., your code snippet does this: if `x` is a [keyword](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_kwd.htm) (a [symbol](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/t_symbol.htm) interned in the [`KEYWORD`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/11_abc.htm) package) then it returns an "ordinary" symbol with the same name interned in the current package [`*package*`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_pkg.htm) (otherwise it returns `x`).